# How can I backup only certain folders using Deja Dup?

Tags: 14.04, backup, deja-dup

I want to backup only my Documents Folder and not my complete home folder.

I tried doing so by including the Documents folder in " Folders to save"
while adding all others to " Folders To Ignore" but it still backed up all of my home!

So how do I do backup selective folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Déjà Dup you should have two options relevant for your question: 'folders to save' and 'folders to ignore'.

1. In 'folders to save' you should **select your home folder and press the minus sign**. If you do not do get rid of the home folder in the 'folders to save' list, then the home folder will also be backed up. I think that is your problem.
2. Then in 'folders to save' you press the plus sign and add your Documents folder.
3. You can still choose to ignore specific folders *in* your Documents folder using the 'folders to ignore' option. But if you want the entire Documents folder there is no reason to add anything here.

Comment: omg! i didnt realise the jome folder was there! LOL... thanx a lot :D